# unit getString with dynamic placeholders

Tags: android

How do you unit test a getString with placeholder that change dynamically?

If just doing it like this

```
 `when`(application.getString(R.string.anString,"args"))
            .thenReturn("mph")
```

it is just static. If I called the function that changed the text 'args' to something different, it would only return "mph" because I set it on `when`(). Is it possible to test a getString with dynamically changing placeholder? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On mockito

```
`when`(getString(R.string.withPlaceHolder)).thenReturn("#$1s string with placeholder")
```

On class being tested dont use getString with second parameter. Instead use String.Format()

```
String.format(getString(R.string.withPlaceholder),"placeholder text here")
```